# Solving equations in cosines

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory

Consider the equation $9x^4+27x^3-33x^2-153x-101=0$. Its Galois Group is $C_4$. That means by Kronecker-Weber theorem that it is solvable in cosines. How can you find this solution?

For example, $x^3-3x+1$ has three nice roots: $2\cos{\pi\over 9}$,$2\cos{7\pi \over 9}$,$2\cos{13\pi \over 9}$. Of course, the equation above won't have such nice roots: but they must be expressible as linear combinations of cosines!

I am really interested in finding them. Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for the roots? A procedure to find the roots? IT turns out that this can be solved by solving only quadratic functions, and so can be expressed using radicals. Is that what you want?Here are the roots: $[-\frac{\sqrt{6}\,\sqrt{13}+2\,\sqrt{5}\,\sqrt{13-3\,\sqrt{13}}+3\,\sqrt{6}}{4\,\sqrt{6}},-\frac{\sqrt{6}\,\sqrt{13}-2\,\sqrt{5}\,\sqrt{13-3\,\sqrt{13}}+3\,\sqrt{6}}{4\,\sqrt{6}},-\frac{2\,\sqrt{5}\,\sqrt{3\,\sqrt{13}+13}-\sqrt{6}\,\sqrt{13}+3\,\sqrt{6}}{4\,\sqrt{6}},\frac{2\,\sqrt{5}\,\sqrt{3\,\sqrt{13}+13}+\sqrt{6}\,\sqrt{13}-3\,\sqrt{6}}{4\,\sqrt{6}}]$

Comment: How do you know that the Galois group is $C_4?$

Comment: No, I can find roots using Ferrari's method myself

Answer (score 2):

Here's a sketch of an algorithm. (No guarantees of speed.) Let $\alpha$ be a root of the polynomial $f$.

- Compute the discriminant of $\mathbb Q(\alpha)$. Here it's $d:=3^2 \cdot 5^2 \cdot 13^3$.

We know that $\alpha \in \mathbb Q(\zeta_{d})$, but the degree is too large to compute in.

By Galois theory, there is a subgroup $H$ of $(\mathbb Z/d)^{\times}$ such that $\mathbb Q(\alpha)=Q(\zeta_{d})^H$, where the element $j\in (\mathbb Z/d)^{\times}$ is associated with $\zeta_d\mapsto \zeta_d^j$ in $G(\mathbb Q(\zeta_d)/\mathbb Q)$. We have $\mathbb Q(\zeta_{d})^H=\mathbb Q(\beta)$ where $\beta =\sum_{j\in H}\zeta^j$ is a sum of roots of unity (and hence cosines). How to find $H$?

Define the splitting set $\text{Spl}(f)$ to be the $p$ such that $f$ splits completely modulo $p$. By class field theory, $\text{Spl}(f)\bmod d=H$ (except possibly for primes that ramify).

- Compute $H\subseteq (\mathbb Z/d)^{\times}$ by seeing if $f$ splits completely modulo lot of small primes, until these primes generate a subgroup of index 4.
- Let $\beta =\sum_{j\in H}\zeta^j$ (probably find a quadratic satisfied by $\beta$ first) and factor $f$ in $\mathbb Q(\beta)$.